# Angular Filter wont work with multiple values

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I can't get my search field to filter my data from my .json file below.
As soon as i start typing in the search fields, all of the items disappear.

Here is my json file that works as my database.

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "firstName": ["Jack", "text"],
    "lastName": ["Rackum", "text"],
    "phone": ["33221122", "tel"]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "userId": 1,
    "firstName": ["Ellery", "text"],
    "lastName": ["Queen", "text"]
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "userId": 1,
    "firstName": ["Minnie", "text"],
    "lastName": ["Mouse", "text"]
}]
```

And here is my views file for the front-end

```
<div class="input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Søg" ng-model="query.$">
    <i class="icon"></i>
</div>


<div class="item" ng-repeat="child in children | filter:query">
    <img class="image" src="images/children/1.jpg">
    <div class="content" >
            <div class="header">
            <a>
                    {{ child.firstName[0] }} {{ child.lastName[0] }}
            </a>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my controllers.js file

```
angular.module('ContactsApp')
    .controller('ListController', function ($scope, Contact) {
        $scope.children = Contact.query();
        $scope.fields = ['firstName', 'lastName'];

        $scope.firstname    = ['firstName'];
        $scope.lastname     = ['lastName'];
        $scope.phone        = ['phone'];
    });
```

And finally my factories file

```
angular.module('ContactsApp')
    .factory('Contact', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/child/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            'update': { method: 'PUT' }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't the ng-model just be "query" without the ".$"

Comment: I read in the documentation that the ".$" would make it work with multiple values. If i remove it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm assuming Contact is the service holding the data, what is the query() method referencing?

Comment: Contact is my factory (if that is the right expression), i added the file to the Question above.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like filters don't work well with searching within arrays. You might need to change your data structure.

Here's a Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/pC0W6YwhTB9l0CUaZWy0?p=preview

Instead of using

```
{{child.firstName[0]}}
```

I used

```
{{child.firstName}}
```

with the appropriate changes in the data.